# Web Api Post from KnockoutJs ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I didn't find much info on web api post. Here is one blog entry that I find that talk about how to do POST from knockout. [Web Api POST with KnockoutJs ViewModel](http://conficient.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/posting-knockout-json-data-to-webapi-httppost-methods/)

ViewModel :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var QuickEntry = function (_itemPartNumb, _itemDescription, _itemQuanities) {
    this.ItemPartNumb = ko.observable(_itemPartNumb);
    this.ItemDescription = ko.observable(_itemDescription);
    this.ItemQuanties = ko.observable(_itemQuanities);
};

function QuickEntriesViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.quickEntries = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        self.quickEntries.push(new QuickEntry());            
    }

    self.addNewRow = function () {
        self.quickEntries.push(new QuickEntry());            
    }.bind(self);

    self.addToCart = function() {
        var items = ko.toJSON(self);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/DesktopModules/blah/API/Data/Post',
            type: 'POST',
            data: items,
            datatype: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            }
        });
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new QuickEntriesViewModel());
```

DataController (Web Api)

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(quickEntries values)
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    response = values.Items != null ? "some data" : "nothing at all";

    return response;
}

//class
public class quickEntries
{
    public MyQuickEntry[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyQuickEntry
{
    public string ItemPartNumb { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string ItemQuanties { get; set; }
}
```

This is what is passing to web api POST method from fiddler:

> {"quickEntries":[{"ItemPartNumb":"bob","ItemDescription":"bob","ItemQuanties":"bob"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}

Does anyone have experience with passing a array of json objects to web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out I need to rename my class.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<QuickEntry> quickEntries { get; set; }
}

public class QuickEntry
{
    public string ItemPartNumb { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string ItemQuanties { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are sending the ViewModel, not the array of objects:

```
var items = ko.toJSON(self);
```

This turns the entire ViewModel object into JSON.  Try converting just the array:

```
var items = ko.toJSON(self.quickEntries);
```

Comment: ko.toJSON(self.quickEntries); this didn't work. Fiddler return 500 error. It turn out that I need to rename my json class.

Comment: I missed that - hard to see those things sometimes! And casing can sometimes drive you up the wall with AJAX as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following is not a direct answer - but some useful links for using Knockout with Web API (though I have not tried development with knockout yet, the articles are informative)

1. [Single-Page Applications: Build Modern, Responsive Web Apps with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx)
2. [KNOCKOUTJS AND WEBAPI TRICKS ARE FOR POCO, KIDS.](http://driftboatdave.com/2014/04/03/knockoutjs-and-webapi-tricks-are-for-poco-kids/)
3. [Single Page Application: KnockoutJS template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template)
4. [Using AngularJS to send parameters to Web API](http://humblebee.me/2014/01/12/using-angularjs-to-send-parameters-to-web-api/)